# correct positioning if statement in a function with for loop

Tags: python, function, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to execute the following code that searches for a mac address in a text file and if found it asks if the user wants to retrieve device information by calling API based on the found IP and password. also, it gives the user the option to start a new search or to quit.

This part works perfectly if a search is matched. the problem here when the search does not match!
it executes " No match found! " correctly in the first trial and then it goes over the function again but if the user is re-entered a mac address that does not have a match again, the code does not re-execute again and ends the program.

below is the code

```
import http.client
from base64 import b64encode
import ssl
import json


def search_mac():
    with open(r"C:\Users\afahmy\Desktop\final.txt", "r") as output_file:
        search = input("Enter mac-address: ")
        search = search.lower().replace(':', '')
        for line in output_file:
            ip = line.split(',')[0]
            # print(ip)
            password = line.split(',')[1]
            # print(password)
            mac = line.split(',')[2].rstrip()
            # print(mac)
            if search == mac:
                print(format("IP:" + ip + "\n" + "password:" + password))
                if input("Do you want to retrieve device information?[y/n]") == 'y':
                    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
                    auth_string = "Polycom:"
                    admin_password = auth_string + password
                    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(ip)
                    userandpass = b64encode(admin_password.encode('UTF-8')).decode('ascii')
                    headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % userandpass}
                    conn.request("GET", "/api/v1/mgmt/device/info", headers=headers)
                    res = conn.getresponse()
                    data = res.read()
                    json_format = json.loads(data)
                    dictionary = json_format["data"]
                    dictionary_new = {k: dictionary[k] for k in dictionary.keys() - {'IPV6Address', 'DeviceType', 'DeviceVendor', 'AttachedHardware'}}
                    for item in dictionary_new.items():
                        print(item)
                if input("Do you want to make another search?[y/n]:") == 'y':
                    search_mac()
                else:
                    print("Thank you!")
                    exit()


search_mac()
print("No Match!")
if input("Do you really want to make another search?[y/n]:") == 'y':
    search_mac()
else:
    print("Thank you for your time!")
```

Here is the output when I enter the incorrect mac address the first time (works well) and the second time (here is the problem).

```
Enter mac-address: 64167f185bf30000 <<<< i added 4 zeros to be a wrong one
No Match!
Do you really want to make another search?[y/n]:y
Enter mac-address: 64167f185bf3     <<<< entered a correct one
IP:10.10.10.4
password:Password!
Do you want to retrieve device information?[y/n]n
Do you want to make another search?[y/n]:y
Enter mac-address: 64167f185bf300   <<<< again a mac address that does not have a match

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is working fine!

Your are waiting a No match, true?. You need to move `print("No Match!")` inside `def search_mac()`

The code prints the firts "No match" outside de function, but look to inside de function, there isn't a "No match". This is a logical bug from developer, but the code is doing his job

Here quick implementations that does your work. But this code is very basic, can have logical errors and could be impoved with:

- deal with duplicated macs
- while True loop that exits catching signals
- read only once the file
- memory leak, you can open bilion of million of thousand times `search_mac()` without close olders

````
def search_mac():
    with open(r"C:\Users\afahmy\Desktop\final.txt", "r") as output_file:
        found = False
        search = input("Enter mac-address: ")
        search = search.lower().replace(':', '')
        for line in output_file:
            ip = line.split(',')[0]
            # print(ip)
            password = line.split(',')[1]
            # print(password)
            mac = line.split(',')[2].rstrip()
            # print(mac)
            if search == mac:
                print(format("IP:" + ip + "\n" + "password:" + password))
                if input("Do you want to retrieve device information?[y/n]") == 'y':
                    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
                    auth_string = "Polycom:"
                    admin_password = auth_string + password
                    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(ip)
                    userandpass = b64encode(admin_password.encode('UTF-8')).decode('ascii')
                    headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % userandpass}
                    conn.request("GET", "/api/v1/mgmt/device/info", headers=headers)
                    res = conn.getresponse()
                    data = res.read()
                    json_format = json.loads(data)
                    dictionary = json_format["data"]
                    dictionary_new = {k: dictionary[k] for k in dictionary.keys() - {'IPV6Address', 'DeviceType', 'DeviceVendor', 'AttachedHardware'}}
                    found = True
                    for item in dictionary_new.items():
                        print(item)
                    break
        if not found:
            print("No Match!")
        if input("Do you want to make another search?[y/n]:") == 'y':
            search_mac()
        else:
            print("Thank you for your time!")
            exit(0)

search_mac()```
````

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, it is actually me who wrote the code but I am still a beginner in python. when I run the code with your amendation if I enter the correct mac address it prints (No Match!) until it breaks after catching the match. and if I enter a wrong mac it prints (no match!) as much as the lines of the text. before prompting the next question. I don't want this behavior, if there is a match I just want a print out of the (IP, password).

Comment: oh, you are true... OK i will edit the response... Try now!

Comment: @gillito Thanks man, this helps a lot! i made a little amendation and all the tests pass successfully now! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks much @gilito!! the code works like 95% correct, except for it prints No Match! after a new prompt

Output:

```
Enter mac-address: 64167f185bf3
IP:10.10.10.5
password:Password!
Do you want to retrieve device information?[y/n]n
No Match!    <<<<<<<<<<< unwanted line
Do you want to make another search?[y/n]:
```

I built on the top of the amendation you did and added a while loop to check within the first block if the user wants to make a new search and if not it exits the program.

so the fully working code is below

```
def search_mac():
    with open(r"C:\Users\afahmy\Desktop\final.txt", "r") as output_file:
        found = False
        search = input("Enter mac-address: ")
        search = search.lower().replace(':', '')
        for line in output_file:
            ip = line.split(',')[0]
            # print(ip)
            password = line.split(',')[1]
            # print(password)
            mac = line.split(',')[2].rstrip()
            # print(mac)
            if search == mac:
                print(format("IP:" + ip + "\n" + "password:" + password))
                entry = input("Do you want to retrieve device information?[y/n]")
                while entry == 'y':
                    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
                    auth_string = "Polycom:"
                    admin_password = auth_string + password
                    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(ip)
                    userandpass = b64encode(admin_password.encode('UTF-8')).decode('ascii')
                    headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % userandpass}
                    conn.request("GET", "/api/v1/mgmt/device/info", headers=headers)
                    res = conn.getresponse()
                    data = res.read()
                    json_format = json.loads(data)
                    dictionary = json_format["data"]
                    dictionary_new = {k: dictionary[k] for k in dictionary.keys() - {'IPV6Address', 'DeviceType', 'DeviceVendor', 'AttachedHardware'}}
                    found = True
                    for item in dictionary_new.items():
                        print(item)
                    break
                else:
                    if input("Do you want to make another search?[y/n]:") == 'y':
                        search_mac()
                    else:
                        print("Thank you for your time!")
                        exit(0)
        if not found:
            print("No Match!")
        if input("Do you want to make another search?[y/n]:") == 'y':
            search_mac()
        else:
            print("Thank you for your time!")
            exit(0)


search_mac()
```